# Android NullPointerException Toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener null object reference

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
 android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(android.view.View$
 OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

it happen on

```
 toolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
```

have the same problem "null object reference".

my team separate file to fragment and all action listener in MainActivity is broke down but we want to separate to fragment like this, but I can't find why separate file to fragment it will null object reference

Here XML fragment_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"><!--set tool bar right to left set drawer to right-->



    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pamba_icon_id"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pambaicon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/filter_icon_id"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/filter"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.533" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPaper_id"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation_id"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
            app:theme="@style/BottomNavigationTheme"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorGray"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"><!--set tool bar right to left set drawer to right-->

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here MainFragment

```
import...

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainFragment() {
        super();
    }

    public static MainFragment newInstance() {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        initInstances(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void initInstances(View rootView) {
        // Init 'View' instance(s) with rootView.findViewById here
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    /*
     * Save Instance State Here
     */
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // Save Instance State here
    }

    /*
     * Restore Instance State Here
     */
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore Instance State here
        }
    }
}
```

and MainActivity

```
import...


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    Toolbar toolBar;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    ImageView imageView;
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);
        setTitle(R.string.title);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawe_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.filter_icon_id);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        final ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolBar, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


//        set own toolbar
        toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
        toolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else {
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
            }
        });

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "filter click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation_id);

//        select item from bottom navigation
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.firstpage_id:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.offergape_id:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "offer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.needpage_id:

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "need", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.searchpage_id:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    //close drawer when click back
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)){

            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

//    select item from drawer
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.account_detail_id:

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.trip_detail_id:

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "detail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.mail_id:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.logout_id:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;


        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);

        return true;
    }


}
```

edit add navigation_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawe_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="end">
    <!--set drawer open from right-->

    <include layout="@layout/activity_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:background="@color/colorGray"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
        android:layout_gravity="end"/>
    <!--set drawer open from right-->


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setContentView in onCreate is setting it to R.layout.navigation_drawer.  You didn't provide an example of that, but instead provided an example of R.layout.fragment_main.  I'm thinking you want that one to be your layout instead.  So in onCreate in your activity set your content view to that layout instead:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    ... // The rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: In navigation_drawer.xml, you include activity_main.xml.  Neither navigation_drawer.xml nor activity_main.xml has a toolbar declared in it.  Therefore you are getting a NullPointerException.